# How to safely push to a local git repository?

Tags: git

We have two git repositories `a` and `b`. Both are local repositories. How can I **push** repo `b` to repo `a` and repo `a` to repo `b`?

```
# remove and create new '/tmp/repos'
rm -rf /tmp/repos
mkdir -p /tmp/repos

# create (init) and config repo 'a'
git init /tmp/repos/a
git -C /tmp/repos/a config user.email "a@example.com"
git -C /tmp/repos/a config user.name "name_a"

# clone and config repo 'a' to repo 'b'
git clone /tmp/repos/a /tmp/repos/b
git -C /tmp/repos/b config user.email "b@example.com"
git -C /tmp/repos/b config user.name "name_b"

# create file './text.txt' in repo 'b', add it, and commit it
echo "first line" > /tmp/repos/b/test.txt
git -C /tmp/repos/b add ./test.txt
git -C /tmp/repos/b commit ./test.txt -m "add first line"
```

What I've tried so far is to set `a` as a bare repository, push from `b` to `a`, and reset `a` to a non-bare repository:

```
git -C /tmp/repos/a config --bool core.bare true
git -C /tmp/repos/b push origin master
git -C /tmp/repos/a config --bool core.bare false
```

But this is not a solution because both repositories must have a working dir and we cannot depend on the status of the other repository.

Please note that I wish to **push from repo `b` to repo `a`** (or something equivalent). I'm aware that I can pull repo `b` from repo `a`. But this is **not** what I need.

```
git -C /tmp/repos/a pull /tmp/repos/b
```

Btw, currently we're using an intermediary local repo `c`.
We are searching for a way to avoid such third (common) repository.
Kind of real distributed without a central repository.
I understand using the common repository is safe, robust and simple.
What I'm interested in is to understand how it could work without it,
and learn where the problems are when two repositories with working trees communicate directly.
In other words: if it is not safe, robust and simple, I would like to really understand exactly why.

Comment: Do you mean something like a git submodule? https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: what are you trying to do? why both repositories must have a work tree? should you consider rsyncing them to each other?

Comment: @McLemore: Not exactly. AFIK submodules are not intended to work in a symmetric way. i.e. A as submodule of B and B as subodule of A.

Comment: @wolfrevo, yeah I see what you mean.

Comment: @eis: I meant working dir. I've updated it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have 2 repos locally which (simplifying) looks like this:

```
a
|- .git
|- foo.txt
```

and

```
b
|- .git
|- bar.txt
```

And now you want to push from repo A to repo B? This is unusual setup as in general you do not push to working repo, but to remote repo. So in this case you would create 3rd repo:

```
mkdir c.git && cd c && git init --bare
```

And you would use that repo as your "remote" by:

```
git remote add origin /path/to/c.git
```

And then you can work with it as with any other remote repo.

But if you really want to push to working repo then you need to push to `.git` folder, so your command would look like:

```
git push /path/to/b/.git master
```

However remember that this will only update Git dir and working tree will remain untouched until someone come and do `git checkout master`.